# Multiple Images in one Slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, shopify-template

I am using the `minimal theme` in `Shopify` and have created a `slideshow` with 4 images but its being vertically display instead of horizontally displayed. How do I change it to be display horizontally instead of vertically. I have tried looking for a solution but just can't seem to find it.Below is my attempted code for getting a multiple image slider that is horizontally displayed. Image attached is what I am trying to achieve.

[image: What I would like to achieve]

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 heroSlider-fixed">
    <div class="overlay">
  </div>
     <!-- Slider -->
    <div class="slider responsive">
      <div>
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/8235/8334/files/shoes.PNG?11833828067426270267" alt="shoes" height="100" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/8235/8334/files/bags.PNG?11833828067426270267" alt="bags" height="100" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/8235/8334/files/Clothing.PNG?11833828067426270267" alt="clothing" height="100" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/8235/8334/files/formal.PNG?11833828067426270267" alt="formal" height="100" width="100" />
      </div>
    </div>
             <!-- control arrows -->
            <div class="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
<style>
html {box-sizing: border-box;}
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing: inherit;}

img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 5px;
}


.slick-dots {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
padding: 0;
li {
display:inline-block;
margin-left: 4px;
margin-right: 4px;
&.slick-active {
  button {
    background-color:black;
  }
}
button {
  font: 0/0 a;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
  background-color:#999;
  border:none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
    :hover{
        background-color: black;
    }
}
}

/* Custom Arrow */
.prev{
color: #999;
position: absolute;
top: 38%;
left: -2em;
font-size: 1.5em;
    :hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        color: black;
    }
}
.next{
color: #999;
position: absolute;
top: 38%;
right: -2em;
font-size: 1.5em;
:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        color: black;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.next {
    display: none !important;
}
}
</style>
```

#### Javascript

```
<script>
$('.responsive').slick({
dots: true,
prevArrow: $('.prev'),
nextArrow: $('.next'),
infinite: false,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 4,
responsive: [
{
  breakpoint: 1024,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 600,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
}
// You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
// settings: "unslick"
// instead of a settings object
]
});
</script>
```

Any links or code changes will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're only referencing the Slick Slider JS files, not the CSS files, causing it to stack like this. I copied your code exactly, ensuring the `slick-theme.css` and `slick.css` files were included, and it works as it should.

```js
$('.responsive').slick({
dots: true,
prevArrow: $('.prev'),
nextArrow: $('.next'),
infinite: false,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 4,
responsive: [
{
  breakpoint: 1024,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 600,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
}
// You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
// settings: "unslick"
// instead of a settings object
]
});
```

```css
html {box-sizing: border-box;}
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing: inherit;}

img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 5px;
}


.slick-dots {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
padding: 0;
li {
display:inline-block;
margin-left: 4px;
margin-right: 4px;
&.slick-active {
  button {
    background-color:black;
  }
}
button {
  font: 0/0 a;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
  background-color:#999;
  border:none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
    :hover{
        background-color: black;
    }
}
}

/* Custom Arrow */
.prev{
color: #999;
position: absolute;
top: 38%;
left: -2em;
font-size: 1.5em;
    :hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        color: black;
    }
}
.next{
color: #999;
position: absolute;
top: 38%;
right: -2em;
font-size: 1.5em;
:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        color: black;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.next {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 heroSlider-fixed">
    <div class="overlay">
  </div>
     <!-- Slider -->
    <div class="slider responsive">
      <div>
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/8235/8334/files/shoes.PNG?11833828067426270267" alt="shoes" height="100" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/8235/8334/files/bags.PNG?11833828067426270267" alt="bags" height="100" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/8235/8334/files/Clothing.PNG?11833828067426270267" alt="clothing" height="100" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/8235/8334/files/formal.PNG?11833828067426270267" alt="formal" height="100" width="100" />
      </div>
    </div>
             <!-- control arrows -->
            <div class="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>

  </div>
</div>
```